# Manipulation of list using sed/awk

Tags: awk, sed, text-formatting

I want to arrange following list into specific format

Current:

```
42.53e-12
43.64e-12
45.78e-12
49.86e-12
57.87e-12
73.68e-12
105.3e-12
```

Needed

```
"42.53e-12, 43.64e-12, 45.78e-12, 49.86e-12, 57.87e-12, 73.68e-12, 105.3e-12"
```

All the numbers separated by commas and the list enclosed in quotes.

Comment: The  output shows comma and space separators `, `, not just commas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{printf (NR>1)?", "$0:"\""$0} END {print "\""}' infile
```

Or in another way:

```
awk '$1="\""$1' RS= ORS="\"\n" OFS=', ' infile
```

Or with combination of `echo` and `sed` commands (assuming there is no whitespaces in your file where shell word splitting is happening on that here)

```
sed 's/ /, /g' <(echo \"$(<infile)\")
```

Comment: awk '$1="\""$1' RS= ORS="\"\n" OFS=', ' infile gives no quotes at the end of the line.

Answer (score 2):

1. Pure *POSIX* `sh`, (since it loads no external programs, this is fastest for small files, if `dash` is the
   current shell):

   ```
   n='"'; while read x; do n="$n$x, "; done < file; echo ${n%,*}\"
   ```
2. Pure `bash`, (fastest for small files, if `bash` is the
   current shell):

   ```
   n=$(<file); echo \"${n//
   /, }\"
   ```
3. Pure `sed`:

   ```
   sed -n 'H;${g;s/\n/, /g;s/, $//;s/, \(.*\)/"\1"/p}' file
   ```
4. Shell tools:

   ```
   /bin/echo -e \"$(xargs printf "%s, " < file)'\b\b"'
   ```

Answer (score 1):

A few approaches to reach the goal:

**`paste`** + **`sed`** solution:

```
paste -d',' -s file | sed 's/,/, /g; s/^\|$/"/g'
```

---

**`python`** solution:

```
python -c 'import sys; print("\""+", ".join(i.strip() for i in sys.stdin)+"\"")' <file
```

---

The output (for both approaches):

```
"42.53e-12, 43.64e-12, 45.78e-12, 49.86e-12, 57.87e-12, 73.68e-12, 105.3e-12"
```

Answer (score 1):

Using Perl (on input from the file `list.txt`):

```
$ perl -e 'printf "\"%s\"\n", join ", ", map { chomp; $_ } <>' list.txt
"42.53e-12, 43.64e-12, 45.78e-12, 49.86e-12, 57.87e-12, 73.68e-12, 105.3e-12"
```

`map` is used to apply `chomp; $_` on each line of input. `chomp` will remove the newline character and the `$_` at the end will make the modified line the output of `map` for that input line.

`join` joins (concatenates) the array that `map` produced, inserting `,␣` (comma-space) between each element.

`printf` prints the concatenated string with `"` at start and end.  The string is outputted with a newline at the very end.

---

Variation using `print` instead of `printf`:

```
perl -e 'print "\"", (join ", ", map { chomp; $_  } <>), "\"\n"' list.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
awk 'BEGIN{ ORS=""; pre="\""}{print pre $0; pre=","}END{ORS="\n";print "\""}'
```

Answer (score 0):

A pure sed solution:

```
sed '${H;g;s/\n//g;b};s/^.*$/&, /;H;d' infile
```

Comment: The *OP* specified surrounding double quotes, but this code doesn't output those.